# blender 2.80 AV sync / frame dropping option

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to edit a video in the blender VSE and, as expected, the playback framerate isn't realtime, which would be fine in a normal situation; however, the audio plays fine, but the frames don't "skip" to catch up with it, so when I pause the video I'm actually in a different place in the sequence than what I hear.

In blender 2.7 this was fixed by using the AV Sync or frame dropping options, but I can't seem to find those in blender 2.80?

Answer (score 2):

It's still at the top of the playback menu but now in it's own drop down sub-menu. It says No Sync by default.

[image]